# Excel VBA error for partially bold string: Variable not defined

Tags: excel, vba, string, bold

I'm very new to VBA and trying to make partially bold string with VBA, but it gives me this error, Compile error, variable not defined.

Here's the code,

`    Option Explicit

```
Sub BoldPart()
Dim Result1, Result2, Result3 As Range
Dim Range1, Range2, Range3, Range4, Range5, Range6 As Range

Set Result1 = Sheet1.Range("A4") 'Result Range
Set Result2 = Sheet1.Range("B2") 'Result Range
Set Result3 = Sheet1.Range("A5") 'Result Range

Set Range1 = Sheet2.Range("Bl") 'Bold Range
Set Range2 = Sheet2.Range("B2") 'Bold Range
Set Range3 = Sheet2.Range("B3") 'Bold Range
Set Range4 = Sheet2.Range("B4") 'Bold Range
Set Range5 = Sheet2.Range("B5") 'Bold Range
Set Range6 = Sheet2.Range("B6") 'Bold Range

Application.EnableEvents = False
'Results
Resultl.Value = "Accendance/Academic profile of your ward," & Range4.Value & ", a Roll No." & Range5.Value & " has promoted to " & Range1.Value & " canberk "
Result2.Value = "Subject:: Progress Report - " & Rangel.Value & " 2017- l8(Session" & Range2.Value &  ")"
Result3.Value = "This is for your info The Issue of Progress Report date is " & Range3.Value


With Result1 'Resultl value
.Characters(InStr(Resultl.Value, Rangel), Len(CStr(Rangel))).Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
.Characters(InStr(Resultl.Value, Range4), Len(CStr(Range4))).Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
.Characters(InStr(Resultl.Value, Range5), Len(CStr(Range5))).Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
.Characters(InStr(Resultl.Value, Range6), Len(CStr(Range6))).Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
End With

With Result2 'Result2 value
.Characters(InStr(Result2.Value, Rangel), Len(CStr(Rangel))).Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
.Characters(InStr(Result2.Value, Range2), Len(CStr(Range2))).Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
End With

With Result3 'Result3 value
.Characters(InStr(Result3.Value, Range3), Len(CStr(Range3))).Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
End With
Application.EnableEvents = True
Sheet1.Active
End Sub
```

`

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mkTuuAWendQ&ab_channel=ExcelAsk%26Answer
This is the video I'm trying to do.
I'm trying to create a VBA to bold some parts of the string. Also, I'd like to know it the code itself is good enough for what I'm trying to do.
Let's say I have a text, a string. And I have some texts in several cells. I want to put those cells in bold to particular areas of that string.

Comment: Do you have a sheet with the code name sheet1 and a sheet with the code name sheet2? code name would be what is not in the parenthesis in the project explorer of the vba window.

Comment: You are also switching between using 1 (one) and l (L) in many of your variables.

Comment: You never declare `Resultl`. Are you mixing this up with `Result1`?  Also, when you declare a bunch of variables on a single line, each one has to have a data type. The variables without a specific data type will be of type variant. In other words, `Dim Result1, Result2, Result3 As Range` declares `Result3` as `Range` and the others as `Variant`.  You probably want `Dim Result1 as Range, Result2 as Range, Result3 As Range`

Comment: I used some OCR to copy the video code, then manually fixed whatever I could. I don't understand exactly how to apply your solution. Could you give me a working xlsm, only that way I can see what codes do exactly what. That would help me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can refactor the "put some text in a cell and bold some parts of it" out into a separate sub.  Using a `ParamArray` for the variable number of replacements makes it flexible.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub BoldPart()
    
    Dim wsOutput As Worksheet, wsInfo as Worksheet

    'Change the sheet names to match your workbook
    Set wsOutput = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'messages show here
    Set wsInfo = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")   'information comes from here

    Bolded wsOutput.Range("A4"), _
       "Accendance/Academic profile of your ward,{1}, a Roll No.{2} has promoted to {3} canberk ", _
        wsInfo.Range("B4"), wsInfo.Range("B5"), wsInfo.Range("B1")
    
    Bolded wsOutput.Range("B2"), _
       "Subject:: Progress Report - {1} 2017-l8(Session{2})", _
        wsInfo.Range("B1"), wsInfo.Range("B2")

End Sub

'Add a message `Msg` to cell `rngMsg`, optionally replacing tags "{1}", "{2}", etc
'   with values from cells passed in to `parts`
Sub Bolded(rngMsg As Range, Msg As String, ParamArray parts() As Variant)
    Dim i As Long, tag, pos As Long, x As Long, txt As String
    rngMsg.Value = Msg
    If Not IsMissing(parts) Then  'was anything passed to `parts` ?
        For i = LBound(parts) To UBound(parts)  'loop over whatever was passed
            x = x + 1                           'tag number
            tag = "{" & x & "}"                 'tag text
            pos = InStr(1, rngMsg.Value, tag)   'tag text position
            If pos > 0 Then                     'tag was found?
                txt = CStr(parts(i).Value)      'replacement text
                rngMsg.Characters(pos, Len(tag)).Text = txt        'replace text
                rngMsg.Characters(pos, Len(txt)).Font.Bold = True  'bold text
            End If
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, I tried to run this code, but it gives me "variable not defined error." It also gave "break code can't run..." something like this error. I'm really new to VBA, could you give me an excel.xlsm that runs it without an error? That would be extremely helpful!

Comment: I made a couple edits to make the code more re-usable.  There are no missing variable declarations  - if you copy/paste it to a regular module in a workbook it will run fine as long as the worksheet names are adjusted.